# How to join one table twice

Tags: sql, database, informix

I want to join a table (zip_code) twice in the following statement. In zip_code table it has two columns zip_id and the corresponding zip_area. I want to map the zip_id in master_table secondary_table to zip_area.

The following statement cannot be executed because the server argues that is has "an on clause has an invalid table reference". How can I archive this join?

```
select 
m.zip_id,
zip1.zip_area as area1,
s.zip_id,
zip2.zip_area as area2
from master_table m, secondary_table s
Left join zip_code zip1 on (zip1.zip_id = m.zip_id)
Left join zip_code zip2 on (zip2.zip_id = s.zip_id)
where m.owner_id = s.owner_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work

```
select 
m.zip_id,
zip1.zip_area as area1,
s.zip_id,
zip2.zip_area as area2
from master_table m join secondary_table s on (m.owner_id = s.owner_id)
Left join zip_code zip1 on (zip1.zip_id = m.zip_id)
Left join zip_code zip2 on (zip2.zip_id = s.zip_id)
```

What's wrong with this?

```
from master_table m, secondary_table s
Left join zip_code zip1 on (zip1.zip_id = m.zip_id)
Left join zip_code zip2 on (zip2.zip_id = s.zip_id)
```

1. **from master_table m, secondary_table s ... where ...** is an "old-style" join (implicit)
2. **secondary_table s LEFT JOIN zip_code ON ...** is an "ANSI-style" join (explicit)
3. Here is some information: http://codeidol.com/community/sql/old-style-versus-ansi-style/3419/
4. in the FROM clause above there is an ANSI-style join: "**secondary_table s** LEFT JOIN **zip_code zip1** on (zip1.zip_id = **m.zip_id**)" which fails because there is no column "m.zip_id"
5. if we change the order of joining: FROM secondary_table s, **master_table m** LEFT JOIN **zip_code zip1** on (zip1.zip_id = m.zip_id) LEFT JOIN **zip_code zip2** on (zip2.zip_id = **s.zip_id**) then the first LEFT JOIN will be OK, but the second will fail (there is no column "s.zip_id")
6. So it's possible to mix old-style joins with ANSI-style joins (at least in Informix), but these joins should be implemented carefully.

Comment: @Marcus Maybe secondary_table doesn't exist and it's just a master_table? In this case just replace the name. The problem with your sql is that you mixed JOIN keyword with implicit join

Comment: what do you mean by mixing JOIN keyword with implicit join

Comment: @Marcus Thornton "master_table m, secondary_table ... where ..." is implicit join, "secondary_table s left join zip_code on ..." is explicit.

Comment: what is the problem with "master_table m, secondary_table ... where ..." implicit join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63454/discussion-between-marcus-thornton-and-multisync).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IBM Documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst103.htm), that should work:

> To create a self-join, list a table twice in the FROM clause, and assign it a different alias each time. Use the aliases to refer to the table in the Projection and WHERE clauses as if it were two separate tables.

I would look elsewhere. For example, make sure the sql seen by the server is what you think.